# ASP.NET Web API 2 - How to enable Basic Authentication in default VS 2013 template?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-401

I've just created `Web Api 2` project in VS and have choosen individual user accounts authentication. I've also created an account using POST (account exists, I checked in created database).

I've tried to invoke action with [Authorize] attribute, but received `401` response. Next I've tried to add `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==` header to request in Fiddler (in `TextWizard` pasted `username:password` and transformed to Base64),

But I'm still getting `401`. What do I need to change in default VS project to enable authentication? To sum up, I get only `401` response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you first need to obtain bearer token by calling /tokens action and then include that token in subsequent requests.

Please take a look at [Secure a Web API with Individual Accounts and Local Login in ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) tutorial for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Basic Authentication is a protocol that is frowned upon and not recommended for any new projects, mostly because the password itself is sent over every request. Over http the password is simply sent in plain text (well base64 enconding) and over SSL it is encrypted but a man in the middle just exposes the password.

Hence it was not included in the built in providers, mostly to encourage you to look at other mechanisms.

The team did build a sample for basic auth available in the aspnet codeplex project that exposes many other samples for Web API, MVC and other projects.

The basic auth sample can be found [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/BasicAuthentication/)

The sample is pretty lengthy, but in general it involves authoring an Authentication Filter and implementing the challenge flow.

This article http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters walks through the design, and the authentication flow for basic auth.

Another approach that works for Web API 1 is detailed in this article, it only works on IIS, and is only recommended if you have to use Web API 1. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication